# How to modify scratch text editor bracket completion plugin?

Tags: code

I want to modify the brackets completion plugin but I can't find a way, is even possible to do so? or I have to write a new plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to get a new brackets completion plugin.

The first one is to propose to developers a modified version in order they accept it and add it to the next update. You can do that by opening a *blueprint* in the Scratch website at *launchpad.net*

To open a new blueprint, visit https://blueprints.launchpad.net/scratch

The other way, if you know Vala, is to copy the plugin code from [launchpad.com](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/scratch/scratch/files/head:/plugins/brackets-completion/) and make your changes, debug and test your plugin. Once it's ready, you can upload to your Launchpad or Github account and import it to a new branch of Scratch at [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/scratch/+new-import) and propose it to merge.

Meanwhile developers decide, you can build it in your system to use it.